# How can I extend a user profile in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to extend the user profile using some of the other questions/answers found here and tutorials on the web.  I'm trying to have the UserProfile model included in the admin so I can change the details of the profile (temporarily for now) but it's not showing up even after I include UserProfile in admin.py, which leads me to believe I'm doing something incorrectly here.

## model.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    quote = models.CharField('Favorite quote', max_length =  200)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

## urlconf

```
(r'^accounts/register/$', 'register'),
```

## view in view.py that registers a user

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('reserve/templates/index.html')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    c = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response("registration/register.html", c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## admin.py

```
from reserve.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

Comment: UserProfile should probably be a OneToOne with User. And is the indentation in your models.py correct? It looks wrong...

Comment: can you include admin.py

Comment: @ColinDunklau: `ForeignKey(unique=True)` *is* `OneToOneField`.

Comment: @scytale: added admin.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way is to inline the `UserProfile` in `User` editing page, in the `admin.py` of one your app which is after `'django.contrib.auth'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from reserve.models import UserProfile

class UserProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfile

class UserWithProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserWithProfileAdmin)
```

Furthermore, you could use the `ForeignKey` itself as the `primary_key`:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)
    quote = models.CharField('Favorite quote', max_length =  200)
```

In that way, you could save the cost of surrogate id, and keep the id of the userprofile same w/ the user's. This enables `UserProfile.objects.get(pk=user_id)` (and `user.get_profile()` is still available of course)

Comment: I edited admin.py to look like the above code but I'm still not able to get UserProfile to show up in the django admin.

Comment: @sharataka oops I've forgotten the register part, see the edit please.

Comment: I added the two lines (unregister/register) and it still isn't visible in the django admin.  I tried it without the unregister line as well and still doesn't work.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this.

Comment: @sharataka What do you mean "invisible in the django admin", is there the line to add/change/delete `User`?